# Installing Zend Framework 2 using pyrus

Tags: zend-framework2, pear, centos5, pyrus

I'm getting an error when trying to download Zend Framework2 view pyrus. Here is the error:

```
# php pyrus.phar . install zf2/Zend_Framework#Standard
Using PEAR installation found at /usr/share/pear/pyrus
PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in phar:///usr/share/pear/pyrus/pyrus.phar/Pyrus_Pharer-0.1.0/php/Pyrus/Package/Dependency/Set/PackageTree.php on line 91
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: extra in phar:///usr/share/pear/pyrus/pyrus.phar/Pyrus_Pharer-0.1.0/php/Pyrus/Package/Dependency/Set/PackageTree.php on line 277
Pyrus\Installer\Exception: Dependency validation failed for some packages to install, installation aborted
 Pyrus\Package\Dependency\Set\Exception: No versions of </< or of its dependencies that can be installed because of
```

I installed pyrus in "usr/share/pear/pyrus/". 
Any ideas why it's not working? I even tried to install another Zend library like this and I get the same error message.

$ php pyrus.phar . install zf2/Zend_Http

Listing channels I get this:

```
[root@apollo pyrus]# php pyrus.phar list-channels
Using PEAR installation found at /usr/share/pear/pyrus
Listing channels [/usr/share/pear/pyrus]:
__uri (__uri)
doc.php.net (phpdocs)
packages.zendframework.com (zf2)
pear.php.net (pear)
pear2.php.net (pear2)
pecl.php.net (pecl)
pyrus.net (pyrus)
```

Then when I try to get the remote list of packages from zf2 it gives me an error:

```
# php pyrus.phar remote-list zf2
Using PEAR installation found at /usr/share/pear/pyrus
Remote packages for channel zf2:
PHP Warning:  current() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in phar:///usr/share/pear/pyrus/pyrus.phar/Pyrus_Pharer-0.1.0/php/Pyrus/Channel/RemoteCategories.php on line 66
```

It seems there must be an error in the Zends repository, because if I list them for pear I get a full list of them using this:

```
# php pyrus.phar remote-list pear
```

Am I doing something wrong?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

FWIW I get exactly the same as you and am assuming the Zend repo is messed up - I cannot begin to guess the timescale to expect it might cease to be messed up. I've switched to using a composer package installer instead and that  seems more promising ;)

M